# Why do I get a "page not found" error when refreshing the page in a vue app?

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application

I created a single page application in vue. It uses the router and everything works fine.
The only problem is that when I'm on any other page than the home page, I can't use the refresh button from the browser. I get a "page not found"...

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit] your question and __add a [example]__, ideally with the code for __router-configuration__. So we can see, why the browser-refresh routes to "page not found". Without the code I can only guess the cause: (a) browser-location not updated with route before, (b) after refresh a server-interaction lead to 404 response.

Comment: Did you read [ask] and [re-search for `[vue.js] route not found`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvue.js%5D+page+not+found)? Then update your question and explain, what question/answers you found (with links) and why they didn't help.

Comment: is this problem happens in dev environment or in production when you deployed your app to a server?

Comment: there was no problem during developpement on the local host. The problem is there only since the site went live on netlify. I found this answer: "

The problem is your web server. Make sure that your web server (Apache, Nginx, Express etc.) always points to the Index.html.

Your web server is not aware that the SPA should do the routing.
" But I dont know what to do with this. The site is hosted on netlify... Is there a way to inform netlify about the spa?